# What's a good resource-saving way to monitor a single Linux server?

Tags: linux, monitoring

I have a single Linux server and it's occasionally unreachable for a while. I want to know what causes this (I suspect either high CPU or Memory usage). I would like to monitor:

- Global CPU/Memory usage
- CPU/Memory usage of individual processes (/etc/init.d services would suffice)
- Network traffic (broken down by process/service would be neat)

I'd like to see a graphs, but I'm not afraid to generate them myself using GNUPlot.

The server resources are limited, so I don't want to use any heavyweight tools.

On Windows machines, there is typically a tool called *perfmon* that can do this - is there any resource-saving tool like that for Linux? All I know is Nagios - too heavy weight for my case?

Comment: I guess the logs did not log something useful?

Comment: Couldn't find anything that would point me to the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Munin should do the job for you. its pretty simple to setup and gives you the basics. It wont scale too well, but it will do a few servers easy.

Comment: Munin looks great for my needs :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [SeaLion](http://sealion.com). Works great for multiple servers and is pretty lightweight for you to use for a single server even. Setup is pretty simple and shows all of what you ask in a simple timeline for easy debugging. Also, it will also warn you when your system is unreachable by email. [image: Outputs timeline]

Besides all of this, the fact that caught me is the flexibility it offers to add any command you wish. So my usage isn't limited to just performance monitoring, I can extend it to monitor any application,etc when i need. I don't have to go looking for another tool. ;)